# Python: Program will not run in other directory

Tags: python, directory

I am running ubuntu 12.04 and running programs through the terminal.  I have a file that compiles and runs without any issues when I am in the current directory. Example below,

```
    david@block-ubuntu:~/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList$ pwd
    /home/david/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList
    david@block-ubuntu:~/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList$ python3.4 bill.py
    ./otherlisted.txt
    ./monthlisted.txt
    david@block-ubuntu:~/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList$
```

Now when I go back one directory and try running the same piece of code, I get an error message, `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`. Below is what happens when I run the sample code one folder back and then the sample code below that.

```
    david@block-ubuntu:~/Documents/BudgetAutomation$ python3.4 /home/david/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList/bill.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/david/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList/bill.py", line 22, in <module>
        bill_no, bill_name, trash = line.split('|', 2)
    ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

The code, `bill.py`, below.  This program reads two text files from the folder that it is located in and parses the lines into variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob

# gather all txt files in directory
arr = glob.glob('./*.txt')
arrlen = int(len(arr))

# create array to store list of bill numbers and names
list_num = []
list_name = []

# for loop that parses lines into appropriate variables
for i in range(arrlen):
    with open(arr[i]) as input:
        w = 0 ## iterative variable for arrays
        for line in input:
            list_num.append(1) ## initialize arrays
            list_name.append(1)

            # split line into variables.. trash is rest of line that has no use
            bill_no, bill_name, trash = line.split('|', 2)

            # stores values in array
            list_num[w] = bill_no
            list_name[w] = bill_name

            w += 1
```

What is going on here?  Am I not running the compile and run command in the terminal correctly?  Another note to know is that I eventually call this code from another file and it will not run the for loop, I am assuming since it doesn't run unless its called from its own folder/directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [eomer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114648/908494), the problem is that `'./*.txt'` is a relative path—relative to the current working directory. If you're not running from the directory that all those `*.txt` files are in, you won't find anything.

If the `*.txt` files are supposed to be *in the same directory as the script*, use *the same directory as the script*, not *the current working directory*.

The standard way of doing that is to put code like this at the top of your script:

```
import os
import sys

scriptdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

- [`argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) gets the path to the script itself. So, if you ran the script as `python BillList/bill.py`, this will be `'BillList/bill.py'`.<sup>*</sup>
- [`dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) just takes a path to a file, and gives you the path to the directory the file was in.  So, in this case, `BillList`.
- [`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) normalizes and absolutizes the path.<sup>**</sup> So, you'll get `/home/david/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList/`. And that's the directory the `*.txt` files are in.

Then, instead of this:

```
glob.glob('./*.txt')
```

… you do this:

```
glob.glob(os.path.join(scriptdir, '*.txt'))
```

---

<sub>* Actually, on some platforms you will get an absolute path here, rather than relative, meaning the later `abspath` is unnecessary. But for portability, it's worth doing. A bigger problem is that in some cases you will get just `bill.py`, with no path. There used to be cases where it was worth checking for that and trying `__file__` instead, but as far as I know that isn't true on any modern platform—and there are cases where `__file__` is wrong but `argv[0]` is right.</sub>

<sub>** For a relative path, it absolutizes it relative to the current working directory. That's why it's important to do this at the top of the script—in case someone does an `os.chdir` later.</sub>

Comment: Yeah I agree that is much more elegant solution. @young_buffett this should be your answer.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot! I understand the problem now.  This will work for me I am sure.  *thumbs up* for everyone a part of this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem starts in line 5:

```
arr = glob.glob('./*.txt')
```

You are telling glob to look in the local directory for all .txt files. Since you are one directory up you do not have these files.

You are getting a ValueError because the line variable is empty.

As it is written you will need to run it from that directory.

Edit:
The way I see it you have three separate options.

1. You could simply run script with the full path (assuming it is executable)

   ~/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList/bill.py
2. You could put the full path into the file (although not very Pythonic)

   arr = glob.glob('/home/[username]/Documents/BudgetAutomation/BillList/*.txt')
3. You could use [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv) to pass the path in the file. This would be my personal preferred way. Use os.path.join to put the correct slashes.

   arr = glob.glob(os.path.join(sys.argv[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv), '*.txt'))

Comment: I see... That makes sense.  Do you have a solution for fixing this problem? Obviously I want to be able to run/call it from other files and directories.

Comment: Those are good suggestions in general… but in this case, the text files are apparently supposed to be in the same directory as the script, so there's a simpler choice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create that range object to iterate over the glob result. You can just do it like this:

```
for file_path in arr:
    with open(file_path) as text_file:
        #...code below...
```

The reason of why that exception is raised, I guess, is there exist text files contain content not conforming with your need. You read a line from that file, which is something may be like "foo|bar", then the splitting result of it is ["foo", "bar"].

If you want to avoid this exception, you could just catch it:

```
try:
    bill_no, bill_name, trash = line.split('|', 2)
except ValueError:
    # You can do something more meaningful but just "pass"
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use absolute path `arr = glob.glob('./*.txt')` here.

Do something like `arr = glob.glob('/home/abc/stack_overflow/*.txt')`

If possible use below code

```
dir_name = "your directory name" # /home/abc/stack_overflow
[file for file in os.listdir(dir_name) if file.endswith('txt')]
```

This will provide you with list of files that you want to `glob` with